# Guitar Amp Humming (interference?)

Tags: ground-loop, guitar-amplifier, hum, buzzing

So my amp worked perfectly fine in my old setup in another part of the house, but in my new setup it buzzes when I connect a cable, and with a guitar. I thought it was a grounding issue, but it didn't improve with everything plugged into a power conditioner. Also, running a extension cable from the original outlet to the new room created the same buzz as the new outlet. I tested multiple cables and nothing changed. Also, it seems to change a little based off the direction of my guitar, or cable. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like your new room may be introducing a new source of magnetic interference. Lights on a dimmer switch for instance. See if turning off all nearby lights and appliances helps. Hopefully you can isolate the source.

Answer (score 0):

It’s most likely caused by induction- if the AC supply is more or less in a loop around the problem location then it will act like one turn on an air-cored transformer- very little energy will be involved but enough to create audible hum.  It’s can be rather difficult to pin down the cause (perhaps try pulling circuit breakers and running an extension lead to identify the circuit that’s the culprit, but resolving it is another matter.  Another possibility is that a badly-behaved load is causing interference on that circuit - try switching everything else off and see if you can isolate it.

Comment: Like I said, I tried running an extension from the other outlet across the house that worked fine, but the buzz was the same. Also sorry I don't have much electrical knowledge...